# Interpolating Wigner's semicircle and Girko's circular law

Tags: random-matrices, eigenvalues

I am relatively new to the field of random matrices, and I suspect this may be relatively well-known.

Consider the real $N$ x $N$ matrix $O$ with i.i.d. standard normal entries, and consider the following combination

$$M = \cos(\theta)\left(\frac{O+O^T}{2}\right)+\sin(\theta)\left(\frac{O-O^T}{2}\right)$$

for $\theta$ in $[0,\pi/2]$. What is the limiting density of the eigenvalues of $M/\sqrt{N}$?

---

There are a few nice values of $\theta$ for which there are textbook results.

$\theta=0$ corresponds to a $GOE$ matrix for which the eigenvalues are purely real and distributed between $-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ according to Wigner's $\rho(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{2-x^2}$.

$\theta=\pi/4$ corresponds to a matrix with random normal entries for which the eigenvalues follow  Girko's circular distribution; that is, the complex eigenvalues are uniformly distributed within the disk of radius $1/\sqrt{2}$. Though the number of points that are exactly on the real axis grows with $N$, the fraction of such points ultimately vanishes.

$\theta=\pi/2$ corresponds to an anti-Hermitian matrix with imaginary eigenvalues that follow Wigner's semicircle on the imaginary axis.

(Note that Wigner's semicircle and Girko's circle refer to different objects; the first the shape of the density and the latter the boundary of the support of the density.)

---

Numerically, the eigenvalues for generic values of $\theta$ fall uniformly into an ellipse that interpolates between the various laws above. Empirically, the horizontal diameter of the ellipse appears to be $2\sqrt{2} \cos(\theta)^2$ while the vertical diameter is $2\sqrt{2} \sin(\theta)^2$. Here are some scatterplots of the eigenvalues of $M$ for a single $N=1000$ instance of $O$:

[image]

I am happy to accept either references or (potentially heuristic) calculations deriving the asymptotic density of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This interpolating ensemble is known as the [real elliptic Ginibre ensemble](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5645). The eigenvalues $E=x+iy$ in the complex plane fill for $N\gg 1$ the ellipse
$$\left(\frac{x}{1+\cos 2\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{1-\cos 2\theta}\right)^2\leq 1.$$
I notice a factor of two difference with the plots in the OP, something to check.